# How to configure an Extension Library Rest Service so I can delete documents from a KendoUI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, xpages, kendo-ui-grid

My KendoUI grid gets data from a viewJsonService Rest service in an Xpages. I would like to write another Rest Service to be able to delete documents from the grid, but cannot figure it out.

How do you do a delete using Rest Services in Xpages?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **xe:documentJsonService** with

- HTTP method DELETE or
- HTTP method POST and X-HTTP-Method-Override header DELETE

Have a look [here](http://www.assono.de/blog/d6plinks/REST-Services-with-the-XPages-Extension-Library) for more information.